# Should there be some FAQ for Tag Synonyms Voting

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I probably missed it, but I had assumed that once you could propose synonyms you would be able to vote on them.  After I figured out how to propose one it seemed it was the only one in the system until I noticed there were more on the all tab and I eventually found this:

[Show synonym suggestions awaiting my vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote)

I can somewhat see the point of that decision, but it took a while to figure out what was going on and I still don't think I understand what the "merge" tag is for.  I am certain I can find that answer as well, but I would suggest either adding some of this to the FAQ or providing some more obvious instruction or description.

Certainly not a huge deal, but for someone that has only lurked before on stackexchange sites it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This now exists as part of the [privileges FAQ page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Clicking on the [create tag synonyms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privilege explains how synonyms work in greater detail.